# defunct process - is it always a child process?

Tags: process, ps

reading on what is a defunct process says that it is a child process which when it terminates/end is not properly handled/killed by its parent.

but viewing on the below output

```
servera> ps -ef | grep defun
cyberark  4036     1   0        - ?           0:00 <defunct>
 oracle  4562  4539   0 09:29:17 pts/3       0:00 grep defun
servera> ptree 4036
4036  <defunct>
  4043  -sh
    4051  passwd root
```

it seems like the defunct process 4036 is the parent process in the ptree ?

Answer (score 3):

A defunct (zombie) process is a process that has terminated, but its parent process hasn't yet done a wait*() on it.  If the parent process terminates before the child process, the child process gets re-parented to init (pid 1), and init performs the wait*() on it when it dies.  Therefore, every defunct process much be a child of some non-init process.

Comment: it seems like the defunct process 4036 parent process is 1. . is 1 consider a init process ?  are we able to see what exactly is the defunct process ?
how is a defunct process still able to have child processes of its own ?

Comment: @Noob Yes, 1 is init.  It's possible for a process to be defunct and have a parent of 1, but normally that should be a *very* short period of time between the time the defunct process gets reparented and the time init responds to the SIGCHLD signal.

Answer (score 2):

PID 4036 is not the root of the process tree; that's PID 1. You asked for the *subtree* with 4036 at the root, so of course you don't see its parent. But it has one. Every process has a parent except PID 1.

Comment: what command should i issue to see its parent ? i always thought ptree will enable us to see the entire tree